# Get the element's order map of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, math

For example:

if input is {2, 8, 5, 6, 10}, 
the output will be {1, 4, 2, 3, 5} .
Since 2 in the minimum in the source array, it's order is 1. 10 is maximum in the array, so it's order is the length of input array.

It's easy to sort the input array first and then find the index of each element. But I want to know if there is a more optimized way.

It doesn't matter whether the order is zero-based or one-based.

Answer (score 1):

- Replace each element by a pair: (element, index). `{2,8,5,6,10}` becomes `{(2,1),(8,2),(5,3),(6,4),(10,5)}`.  Let this array be `A`.
- Sort `A`. You now have `{(2,1),(5,3),(6,4),(8,2),(10,5)}`
- For each `i` from `1` to `length(A)` do `B[A[i].second_element] <- i`.  In your case:
   
   `B[1] <- 1
   B[3] <- 2
   B[4] <- 3
   B[2] <- 4
   B[5] <- 5`
- Now `B={1,4,2,3,5}`.  PROFIT!!!